# Accessing nested repeater's textbox in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to get the nested repeater textbox control  in client side event of parent Repeater control.

I have a checkbox in each repeater item of the parent repeater control and textbox in each repeater item of the child Repeater. On the checkbox change event I need to find if there is any value in the child repeater textbox of that item in the client side.

I gave a class to the textbox, but the below code loops through all the textboxes inside the parent repeater.

$('.RepeaterTextBox').each(function () {
            var txtvalue= $(this).val();

Rendered HTML for a single parent looks like this

```
   <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
          <input id="chkActive_0" name="chkActive" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <div id="divText" style="padding-left: 15px; display: none;">

              <table style="width: 100%">

                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <div id="Category_0">

                              <textarea name="txtCategoryText" rows="2" cols="20"       id="CategoryText_0" class="RepeaterTextbox"></textarea>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                          <div id="Category_1">
                              <textarea name="txtCategoryText" rows="2" cols="20" id="CategoryText_1" class="RepeaterTextbox"></textarea>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far and provide your code please.

Comment: In your serverside code, give each textbox a class. Then in clientside, you can get all `input` controls with that class

Comment: Attach rendered HTML of any single repeater item (parent)

Comment: @RashminJaviya, I included the rendered html of a single repeater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it seems there are multiple textarea you have in nested repeater so the second line in the event handler will loop through each textarea and print value in console.

```
$("[type=checkbox]").on("change", function () {
    var oTexts = $(this).parents("tr").next().find("textarea");
    $(oTexts).each(function (ind, val) { console.log($(val).val()); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checklist `parent()` property

Assuming your rendered html look like this

```
<div id="repeater_435734957439857435">
   <input type="text" class="RepeaterTextbox">Test</input>
   <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Your checkbox select event can be something like

```
$(this).parent().find(".RepeaterTextbox")[0].text();
```

Comment: My textbox is in the child/nested repeater of the parent one

Answer (score 0):

This should work with your markup:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "input:checkbox[name='chkActive']:checked", function () {
        var nexttr = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
        $(nexttr).find('textarea').each(function () {

            alert($(this).val());//Or whatever you want
        })

    });
});
```